# Select tag - using logic to specify the selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form select where by default, I need a 'main' root folder selected, but I also need it to use params if they exist for the selected option.  I've seen examples of using params as the selected unless they're nil.   But, I haven't seen an example of using another value if the param is nil (use this unless it's blank, in which case - use this other thing).

VIEW

```
 <%= f.select :folder_id,  options_for_select(@folders, @folder_to_select )  %>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
if  !params[:contact][:folder_id].nil?
   @folder_to_select = params[:contact][:folder_id].to_i
else
   @folder_to_select = @folders.assoc('MAIN').last.to_i
end
```

Can I get that controller logic functionality all inside Select?

Thanks!

edit:

I missed it but my originall controller code didn't actually work.  I had to check if the [:contact] param was nil before I could check if [:contact][:folder_id] was nil (to avoid a nil error if the top level [:contact] didn't exist.

```
if !params[:contact].nil?
  if !params[:contact][:folder_id].nil?
     @folder_to_select = params[:card][:folder_id].to_i
  else
     @folder_to_select = @folders.assoc('MAIN').last.to_i
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
<%= f.select :folder_id,  options_for_select(@folders, params[:contact][:folder_id].to_i || @folders.assoc('MAIN').last.to_i)  %>
```

Comment: You should get a nil error from the if statement in your original post as well though.  To avoid that I would suggest using a compact if statement: (params.has_key?(:contact) ? params[:contact][:folder_id].to_i : @folders.assoc('MAIN').last.to_i)

Comment: That said I would recommend keeping all this logic in the controller or adding it to a model or module where possible.  All that code clutters up views and makes them harder to understand.

Comment: I'm playing around with it.  What I've noticed so far is my original code actually doesn't work (could have sworn it did).   For some reason a nil check on params[:foo] will work, but params[:foo][:bar] doesn't work.  Like when Ruby just jumps to checking for nil against [:bar] and trips over the fact that the whole [:foo] parent is nil.   I guess in the controller I could add one more logic layer checking if params[:contact] is nil before checking if params[:contact][:folder_id] is nil.   Thanks for all the help - much appreciated!

Comment: oh I understand why I missed it.  When I was first checking the code [:foo] existed but [:bar] didn't.  So I just thought the whole [:foo][:bar] nil check worked.  I got fooled. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Ruby doesn't actually skip over params[:foo], but it's confusing because params[:foo] is actually a valid function call that returns nil.  The problem occurs when you call the [] function on a nil object, since [] isn't defined on nil.  This is a common operation in Ruby and Rails, so it's best to check each layer of the hash: params[:foo].nil? || params[:foo][:bar].nil?.  The best way to think of prams[:foo][:bar] is as two function calls, on for '.[] :foo' and then one for '.[] :bar' on the result of the first operation.